# Set select input value unsing php echo

Tags: php, jquery

I have a select input for categories that set a list (category_id + category_value) from the database using the class categories_list. Now I want to set the value of selected category using get method when a user click on a specific category from another page. My get method is working fine, but the select input doesn't fetch the get variable with php echo.

I have tried to use instead jquery $("select[name='categories_id']").val(); but it works only if i add a clicked event that i don't want it .

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label alignL" for="categories_id">Catégories </label>
            
<select id="categories_id" class="form-control common_selector categories_list" name="categories_id" value" <?php if (isset($_GET["cat"])) { echo  $categorytag; } ?>" >
                
</select>   
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to show your GET values you need to add as <option> tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code example is too vague. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following example.

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label alignL" for="categories_id">Catégories </label>
  <select id="categories_id" class="form-control common_selector categories_list" name="categories_id">
    <option value="1001">Cat 1</option>
    <option value="1002">Cat 2</option>
    <option value="1003" selected>Cat 3</option>
    <option value="1004">Cat 4</option>
    <option value="1005">Cat 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The `<select>` element does not have a `value` attribute.

| Attribute | Description |
| --- | --- |
| autofocus | Specifies that the drop-down list should automatically get focus when the page loads |
| disabled | Specifies that a drop-down list should be disabled |
| form | Defines which form the drop-down list belongs to |
| multiple | Specifies that multiple options can be selected at once |
| name | Defines a name for the drop-down list |
| required | Specifies that the user is required to select a value before submitting the form |
| size | Defines the number of visible options in a drop-down list |

See More: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

You can get the `value` of the element when an `<option>` has been selected.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("Current Value", $("#categories_id").val());
  $("#categories_id").change(function() {
    console.log("Selected", $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label alignL" for="categories_id">Catégories </label>
  <select id="categories_id" class="form-control common_selector categories_list" name="categories_id">
    <option value="1001">Cat 1</option>
    <option value="1002">Cat 2</option>
    <option value="1003" selected>Cat 3</option>
    <option value="1004">Cat 4</option>
    <option value="1005">Cat 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You will want to adjust your PHP to build the Select element and Options properly before sending it to the browser. Then, if you are performing some action via JavaScript or jQuery, it will be done Client side.

Comment: Following your exemple if i add a script like so  ````  $("select[name='categories_id']").val("1003"); ```` the value cat 3 will be selected automatically and this is what i would like to do recover the good id from the first page and use it in the second page like so. Except it's working when the options are defined manually like the exemple. But for my case the options value are loaded with php and fetch with the class category_list. And i don't know why this is not working in this scenario. Thnaks you

Comment: @Yas your statement does not make sense. PHP is executed Server-Side and the resulting HTML is presented to the browser after it is processed. JavaScript is Client-Side and only runs in the browser after the HTML is received. If you're having problems, you need to post a repeatable example of the issue.